# VBA Recordset.GetRows Returns incomplete result set

Tags: sql-server, excel, stored-procedures, adodb, vba

I've met this strange problem:

I have a MSSQL store procedure which has poor performance, so I rewrite it. After rewrite, The new store procedure can still return the same results if called from SSMS or console. But when called by VBA, a few columns of the returned result are empty.

Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
        conn.Open strConnection

```
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
    cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
    cmd.CommandText = "[ops].[spReportsDoAnalyticsForAllProducts]"

    cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    cmd.Parameters.Refresh
    cmd.Properties.Refresh

    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("runId", adInteger, adParamInput)
    cmd("runid") = runid

    Set rs = cmd.Execute

    If Not rs.EOF Then
        data = rs.GetRows
        hasData = True

    End If

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing

    conn.Close
    Set conn = Nothing
```

Above are the VBA code, **rs.GetRows** is the one that returns me incomplete results. I was forced to use the following code to replace it and manually populate the results in VBA:

```
    While Not rs.EOF
        ReDim Preserve data(rs.Fields.count - 1, count)
        For i = 0 To rs.Fields.count - 1
            data(i, count) = rs.Fields(i).Value
        Next i
        count = count + 1
        rs.MoveNext
    Wend
```

I want to know the real reasons that cause **GetRows** not working but **Fields** still working, or is there any alternatives that I can use instead of the while loop.

Comment: Try calling `rs.MoveLast` on the line before your call to `rs.GetRows`.

Comment: no if you move last, no data can be fetched.

Comment: Strange enough, after days of struggling, it cured itself! getRows suddenly worked without any Code or DB change. Yet I'm still wondering what's the cause...

Comment: For the record, I found a way to eliminate this problem: the fields returned from stored procedure cannot be set to varchar(MAX). You can set it to a pretty big size, and the error will be gone immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Get rows is expecting a parameter, the number of rows to retrieve.  See MSDN below.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677500(v=vs.85).aspx

If you return zero or N from your stored procedure as a return code.

Then use that number as a parameter to GetRows().  Then you should be set.

Since I come from VB 2.0 and up, I am used to rs.Fields.

Good luck.

Comment: But All parameters for GetRows are optional: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675120(v=vs.85).aspx  I hold nothing against rs.Fields, its just that in this case when I'm expecting the whole dataset, a while loop is not efficient and reader-friendly. I simply don't understand how come getRows suddenly misfunction when I only update the sp logic. The input and output of the sp remain unchanged the whole time.

Comment: Optional. A GetRowsOptionEnum value that indicates the number of records to retrieve. The default is adGetRowsRest.  What is the value of adGetRowsRest.  These used to be include files in the old days.  What is the value?